# Troubles with jQuery fadeIn() and fadeOut() in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, fadein, fadeout

Have a plugin that I'm working on and I've hit a wall in Chrome. The script works perfectly in FF, but Chrome is not correctly displaying the fadeIn and fadeOut effects. It looks like Chrome is just defaulting to show and hide. Any suggestions?

You can see it in action here: http://heartpublications.com

Here is the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

  function contentRotate(feature) {
 if (doAnimate) {  
   $("#slide1").fadeOut("fast", function (feature) {
     return function () {
    $("#banner div").hide();


    /* FADE IN NEXT ITEM OR GO BACK TO FIRST */
    feature.fadeIn("fast", function () {
      if ($(this).attr("id") == "slide3") {
     setTimeout(function () {
       contentRotate($("#banner div:first"));
     }, 4000);
      }
      else {
        setTimeout(function () {
       contentRotate($(feature.next()));
     }, 4000);
      }
    });
     };
   }(feature));
 }
  }



  var doAnimate = true;

  contentRotate($("#banner div:first"));




});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what happens if you set it to slow instead of fast? It could be that your machine is just too fast

Comment: no difference. still just blinks.

Comment: Wait, I just realized something. What's up with this `return function() {` stuff? I've never seen that. Don't do that; take out that wrapping element and see if it does the same thing.

Comment: removing the wrapping element made no difference in either chrome or FF. I'm leaving it out, but I still have the bug in Chrome. . .

Comment: I also removed the doAnimate declaration and conditional statement. It wasn't necessary to the current application. Still no difference. . .

Comment: @samgerdt ~ Sorry, was afk. Can you update the code in the question to reflect your current codebase?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with jQuery 1.3.2 but it disappeared upgrading to the latest version (1.4.2).